# Thumbnail and sorting information issues of Picture Library in Sharepoint Foundation 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, picture-library, sorting, thumbnail

I have a few questions about SP Foundation 2013.
I'm creating an Intranet page and came across a few issues here - tried to research but just want to have a final advice / suggestion / confirmation.

1. Picture library - I'm using a script to show the name and the title of the person and it's sorting my library in alphabetical order by the picture name which is correct. However, is it possible to add an option to select pictures to be shown only i.e. starting with A, B, C, etc. letters? Great example would be when selecting brands in online shopping webpage. Not sure if it is possible to complete and how if possible?
2. A massive one. I'm a site collection admin and owner overall, so I have full rights. When I'm looking at the picture library in Thumbnails view, it displays correctly for my user on IE and Chrome. When I am looking at the same picture library in thumbnail view on another user that only has a read rights - I can only see the one thumbnail per line but all of them goes down in a column using IE browser. It works well in Chrome (but we are going to use mainly IE for this). On a normal view it should be 6 thumbnail pictures per line and then my provided amount of pictures all together. Do you have any ideas why Read-Only users in IE sees one picture per line but all in one column?

Thanks a mill for brainstorming and help!!

UPDATE:

- Emulation and browser update (from IE10 to IE11) didn't help for the second issue;
- Found that if a user is Intranet Home Owner or Member (has more rights than Read only) - Thumbnails display correctly. Once the user is a Visitor only - Thumbnails displayed in one long column. Any ideas here? I need all of the users to have Read rights only to the picture library, however it should be displaying same for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt to solve your first question I would use SharePoint Search to filter your results.

- Edit page
- Insert a Search Results web part
- Open properties of the web part and click "change query"
- In the Query Text set something like 
  Path:https://url.of.your.sharepoint/sites/Picturelibrary Filetype:PNG {SearchBoxQuery}
- Save
- Add a Search Box web part

People can now search for things like this:

BMW* OR Audi*

They will get all pictures having a BMW or Audi at the beginning of Name, Title or elsewhere in a crawled/mapped property.

Comment: Thanks, Phil!

I've thought about the Search Results - will play around a bit.

The second part, however, didn't work. I've checked Emulation on IE10 - didn't make a chance. I've then upgraded to IE11 and it is still same for Read Only users.
Once I've added test user as an Owner of the site - it displayed thumbnails perfectly. So I believe it is something to do with the permissions level? Once it is visitor with ready only - 400+ thumbnails display in one column. Once it's owner - all works perfectly

Comment: Hm. Really seems to be a permission related problem. But I don't get it why this could happen. We got SharePoint 2013 (Enterprise) as well and are using the (more less than more) satisfying picture libraries. I have never had such an issue and can hardly believe what permissions have to do with it. I am sorry...